# JQuery toggler - Click one toggle should update another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this https://github.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles plugin to toggle an element on my page.

The plugin works fine on one item.

```
$('.toggle').toggles({
    on: true,
    text:{
        on:'COMPLETE',
        off:'INCOMPLETE'
    }
});

$('.toggle').on('toggle', function (e, active) {
    if(active) {
        $(this).removeClass('off');
        $(this).addClass('on');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');
    }
});
```

But I have 2 identical elements, one at the top and one at the bottom of the page.

I am trying to have both updated(toggle) at the same time. I tried just targeting the class but that did not work:

```
$('.toggle').toggles({
    on: true,
    text:{
        on:'COMPLETE',
        off:'INCOMPLETE'
    }
});

$('.toggle').on('toggle', function (e, active) {
    if(active) {
        $('.toggle').removeClass('off');
        $('.toggle').addClass('on');
    } else {
        $('.toggle').removeClass('on');
        $('.toggle').addClass('off');
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

**I have tried using each but it does not quite work**
http://giphy.com/gifs/3o85xxJ7f2fYakUzQs

Comment: you shoul use `each` since you want to remove and add class on multiple elements...

Comment: you have a typo. Where you have `$(this)` you have written `$(.toggle)` but should be `$('.toggle')`

Comment: Thanks Lelio, I have updated. I had the '' in my code. Just not int he question

Comment: you write having tried the "each" method, have you tried the edited @ImreNagy's answer ? What is the code you used on the gif you posted ? Maybe you have to also "toggle" the othe element, and then need a more complexe answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this line

```
$('.toggle').toggles(active);
```

into the .on event like this

```
$('.toggle').toggles({
    on: true,
    text:{
        on:'COMPLETE',
        off:'INCOMPLETE'
    }
});


$(".toggle").on("toggle", function(e, active) {

    $('.toggle').toggles(active);

    if(active) {
        $('.toggle').removeClass('off');
        $('.toggle').addClass('on');
    } else {
        $('.toggle').removeClass('on');
        $('.toggle').addClass('off');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. The docs are not great on the plugin, but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle each element seperately:

```
$('.toggle').on('toggle', function (e, active) {
    $.each($('.toggle'), function(index, element) {
        if(element.hasClass('off')){
            $('.toggle').removeClass('off');
            $('.toggle').addClass('on');        
        }
        if(element.hasClass('on')){
            $('.toggle').removeClass('on');
            $('.toggle').addClass('off');        
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: you have a typo. You have written $(.toggle) but should be $('.toggle')

Comment: are you sure about this code ? I woul have put the `each` inside the `if`. Here you will look at both elements which have different `on` and `off` state, and toggle both...

Comment: Isn't that what the OP tries to accomplish?

Comment: Hmmm, this has to be after the `$('.toggle').on('toggle', function (e, active) {`, not replace it, yeah... can you add the event listener in the answer please to clarify this ? :)